# Styled Speed Dial MUI

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui

Good afternoon. I'm using `Speed ​​dial` component for `MUI` and can't figure out how to style `tooltipTytle`.
I can do something only when all tooltips are shown at once, but this does not suit me and I need them to be shown only on hover. Can this be done somehow?

```
export const WidgetsMenu = () => {
    return (
        <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <SpeedDial
            ariaLabel="SpeedDial openIcon example"
            icon={<SpeedDialIcon openIcon={<CloseIcon />} />}
            className={styles.speedDial}
        >
            {actions.map((action) => (
                <SpeedDialAction
                    key={action.name}
                    icon={action.icon}
                    tooltipTitle={action.name}
                />
            ))}
        </SpeedDial>
        </StyledEngineProvider>
    );
};
```

I use styling through modules, other options do not suit me:

```
.speedDial :global {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3rem;
  right: 3rem;
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    bottom: 2rem;
    right: 1.5rem;
  }

  .MuiSpeedDial-fab {
    color: #070707;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
  }

  .MuiSpeedDialAction-fab {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #070707;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
  }
}
```

`Codesandbox`: https://codesandbox.io/embed/serene-dhawan-sii571?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Could you create a codesandbox ? It will be easier to provide assistance that way

Comment: @RyanZeelie Bro added to description

Comment: Come to the chat room , There is another why I know of : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246507/mui-tooltip-q

Comment: @RyanZeelie Very ty bro. 
You helped me a lot, rays of good for you!
I can't answer in chat, I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Is the componentsProps method going to work for you?

Comment: @RyanZeelie Yes, please post it as an answer, maybe it will help someone besides me

Comment: Great! Glad it's useful! Goodluck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the tooltip component for the SpeedDialAction through componentsProps

```
      <SpeedDialAction
        key={action.name}
        icon={action.icon}
        tooltipTitle={action.name}
        componentsProps={{
          tooltip: {
            sx: {
              bgcolor: "pink",
              color: "white"
            }
          }
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with css/scss modules? I really don't want to mix both of these approaches

Comment: [As noted in the MUI doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tooltip/#props), "It's recommended to use the `slotProps` prop instead, as `componentsProps` will be deprecated in the future."

Comment: @SonNguyen could you fork the sandbox from the original post and show an example? I tried and it seems like slotProps doesnt work. I did read the docs and you are correct. But lacking examples